# Send and receive email with java while hiding the user's email

Tags: java, email, grails

I'm not even sure of the right terminology to ask the question, but here is what I'd like to accomplish.  I've seen it done on sites such as craigslist.

- My website has multiple users.  When a user registers with the site they provide an email address (gmail, hotmail, whatever)
- users are allowed to message each through the website
- When Bob sends a message to Mark through the website, Bob and Mark never see each other's email address
- Bob's message (bob@gmail.com) is sent via email to Mark (mark@abccompany.com)
  -Mark receives the email.  The from and reply-to looks something like this, so Bob's email address is never seen.

  bob smith (d8d8cdd8677031a983148db1823f9b94@reply.mydomain.com)

there should be angle brackets there but I can't get them to display properly.

- Mark replies to the email, and the reply email has the to address as:

bob smith (d8d8cdd8677031a983148db1823f9b94@reply.mydomain.com)

- The mail server decodes the reply to address, figures out who sent it and where it's going, and sends a reply to bob, hiding Mark's real email address.

What is this even called?  Is this a simple manipulation of the message headers to do the hiding?  I need to come up with something similar in my grails app.  A user never sees the real email address unless one user puts it in the actual message body 'hey my real email address is bob@gmail.com, email me there direct.'

Does anyone know if Amazon's SES service supports this type of thing?

Answer (score 0):

Transactional email is one of the correct terms that describes this service.

Amazon does not provide this type of service (as of this writing).  If you google 'transactional email api' there are several services that popup which provide exactly this type of service.